# Замена всех слов в строке, кроме тех, что соответсвуют шаблону. sed, awk

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed, awk

есть строка

14:24:14 текст @vp текст

Нужно с помощью sed или awk или других инструментов

на выходе оставить только @vp

т.е. заменить все слова, что не содержат @ на "", (@ - всегда в начале слова)

либо найти и вывести слова в которх есть @

Comment: Как вариант -  разбить используюя в качестве разделителя " " (пробел) и затем сравнивать каждое слово на совпадение с регэсп (Проверка наличия @)

Comment: `sed -r -n '/@/s/.*(@[^ \t]+).*/\1/gp' /file` -  попробуйте седом вывести

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<!\S)@\S+' file | uniq > outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

Прикольно, что есть этот сервис )

Решение

cat 200408.vp | grep "@" | tr " " "\n" | grep "@" | sort -u

выводим все строки в которых есть @

разделяем по пробелу

и снова выводим, но уже все слова в которых есть @

- в моем случае полезно оставить только уникальные варианты

( опционально можно еще посчитать оличество вхождений wc -l )

Bash мощь )

Comment: ну, вообще-то к программе bash ни вопрос ни ответ не имеют ни малейшего отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант выдачи уникальных слов, начинающихся с `@`, на
*awk*:

```awk
{
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) {
        if ($f ~ /^@/) {
            good[$f] = 1;
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (w in good) {
        print(w);
    }
}
```

Дальше отправить в *sort* без `-u`.